# How to accept the Return or Enter key in a RibbonTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ribbon-control

Really simple question... how do I get the `RibbonTextBox` to accept the <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys to enable multi line text input?

On a normal `TextBox`, I'd just set the [`TextBoxBase.AcceptsReturn` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.acceptsreturn(v=vs.110).aspx) to `True` to set *a value that indicates how the text editing control responds when the user presses the ENTER key*, but that doesn't seem to do anything on the `RibbonTextBox`.

Just to note, the related [`TextBoxBase.AcceptsTab` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.acceptstab(v=vs.110).aspx) also does *not* work on the `RibbonTextBox`, so it seems as though they have simply overlooked these properties when developing the `RibbonTextBox`.

Does anyone know if there is a work around, or will it simply not work?

Comment: Did you try setting it via a setter to the TextBox TargetType? Like `<RibbonTextBox><RibbonTextBox.Resources><Style TargetType="TextBox"><Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True"/></Style></></>`? I couldn't seem to find the default template for it but I'd assume there's one in there somewhere, just may not have that property bound to the template.

Comment: I hadn't tried that, but I just did and unfortunately it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I'd pull out the template for it (since I couldnt find the default in the docs with a quick search) and see if it's actually a TextBox in there or like a ScrollViewer / ContentPresenter or something and see what you're dealing with. If it happens to be the latter you could just replace it with TextBox bound to Content

Comment: It's definitely a `TextBox` because intellisense shows the `TextBoxBase.AcceptsReturn` and `TextBoxBase.AcceptsTab` properties... they just don't work. Good old Microsoft and their half-arsed attitude.